# Trying to convert user define function result into list in python

Tags: python, list, function, loops, shuffle

```
#Password Generator Project
import random
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']

print("Welcome to the PyPassword Generator!")

nr_letters= int(input("How many letters would you like in your password?\n")) 
nr_symbols = int(input(f"How many symbols would you like?\n"))
nr_numbers = int(input(f"How many numbers would you like?\n"))

#Eazy Level - Order not randomised:

#e.g. 4 letter, 2 symbol, 2 number = JduE&!91

def my_function():
  for i in range(1,nr_letters+1):
    variable=random.choice(letters)
    print(variable, end='')

  for j in range(1,nr_symbols+1):
    variable1=random.choice(symbols)
    print(variable1, end='')

  for k in range(1,nr_numbers+1):
    variable2=random.choice(numbers)
    print(variable2, end='')

#Hard Level - Order of characters randomised:

#e.g. 4 letter, 2 symbol, 2 number = g^2jk8&P

#my_function()

function_to_list=my_function()
print[(function_to_list)]
shuffle_my_function=random.shuffle(function_to_list)
print(shuffle_my_function)
```

This is a kind of personal project here my task is to generate a password. On the easy level just print the password sequence wise whereas on the hard level I want my password to be shuffled.
My easy level code is working perfectly but on the hard level, I want to shuffle the result of the easy level for that I thought that if I define a function of the easy part and then somehow convert that function into the list I can easily use shuffle function . so please help me. please try to do give a solution in my way of thinking and then please suggest your way of doing it

Comment: What is `print[(function_to_list)]` supposed to mean? `print` is a function, not a list or dictionary, you don't use `[]` to call it.

Comment: If you have a string `s`, then `list(s)` will turn that into a list of characters.  You can then use `''.join(l)` to go in reverse.  Putting that all together, I think what you want is `''.join(random.shuffle(list(s)))`

Comment: To be able to operate on the result of `my_function`, you need to `return` a value from the function.  You should build up a temporary string and `return` it instead of `print`ing.

Comment: @0x5453 `random.shuffle()` operates in place, it doesn't return the shuffled list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common beginner problem. When you print something, it's there on the screen, but only as text. And the program can't see that text. You have to do something to the variables to keep track of them as you go. In this case, you need to append them to a list. Not only that, but you need to return the list to the caller, so that `function_to_list = my_function()` assigns something other than `None` to `function_to_list`:

```
def my_function():
    list_of_characters = []

    for i in range(nr_letters):
        list_of_characters.append(random.choice(letters))

    for j in range(nr_symbols):
        list_of_characters.append(random.choice(symbols))

    for k in range(nr_numbers):
        list_of_characters.append(random.choice(numbers))

    return list_of_characters
```

Notice that I took out the print statements. That's because a function should do only one thing and do it well. You can print your list and your password as soon as you get them back:

```
list_from_function = my_function()
print(list_from_function)
```

To print the list as a single string, join the letters it contains with the emtpy string:

```
print(''.join(list_from_function))
```

You can shuffle the result, or do whatever you want:

```
random.shuffle(list_from_function)
print(list_from_function)
```

Keep in mind that `shuffle` operates in place and returns `None`. That means that if you try to print its return value, you get nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `for loop`. You can pass argument to `random.choices()` indicating how many items you want.

```py
import random
import string

letters = string.ascii_letters
numbers = string.digits
symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']

# For demo, I hardcoded the numbers
nr_letters = 4
nr_symbols = 5
nr_numbers = 3

# create a list from randomly choosen characters
password_characters = random.choices(letters, k = nr_letters) \
                        + random.choices(symbols, k = nr_symbols) \
                        + random.choices(numbers, k = nr_numbers)

# shuffle the list:
random.shuffle(password_characters)

# convert the list to string
password = ''.join(password_characters)
```

Output:

```py
>>> print(password)
>>> &J0*4oR!I3$!
```